# curl | jq error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading

Tags: unix, curl, jq

The command line is:

```bash
$ curl -v -k "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&ids=Q111" | 
> jq .
```

I use WSL2 to type above command. It show error.

```bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.102.166.224:443...
* Connected to www.wikidata.org (103.102.166.224) port 443 (#0)
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:59 --:--:--     0* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Unknown (21):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, decode error (562):
} [2 bytes data]
* error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:02:00 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:0A000126:SSL routines::unexpected eof while reading
```

I have used `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, `curl -V` display curl's version and openssl's version:

```
curl 7.81.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.81.0 OpenSSL/3.0.2 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.4.8 libidn2/2.3.2 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.2) libssh/0.9.6/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.5.14
Release-Date: 2022-01-05
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

I type the command on cygwin too. It shows different error:

```bash
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.102.166.224:443...
* Connected to www.wikidata.org (103.102.166.224) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0* Recv failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with www.wikidata.org port 443
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer (bytes written: -1)
curl: (35) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Does `curl` produce output? That's the first thing I'd verify. `curl -v` is very helpful too, to get verbose output (without piping to jq)

Comment: Looks like problem with SSL/TLS. Are you behind a corporate proxy or is your TLS traffic being deep-packet inspected? Does it work in your browser/all browsers? This would mean that your communication with the server is not encrypted anymore. Not a solution, but `curl -k` ignores incorrect certificates. `openssl s_client` to verify the certificate of the server (or that of your corporate MitM proxy, respectively)

Comment: curl produce null output. I use vpn, but when I disconnect vpn, the error is same. In chrome and edge browser, it display json data.

Comment: Did you try with `curl -k` as suggested?

Comment: I have tryed `curl -k`. The error is the above.

Answer (score 0):

Start by verifying that curl produces any data at all. Perhaps:

```
curl -s "https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&format=json&ids=Q111" >testcurl.json
```

Then examine the file. Perhaps your URL is incorrect.

You might also consider using jsonlint to examine the resulting file.

Comment: When I enter the URL in browser, it display json data. But I use jsonlint examine testcurl.json, it show error `Error: Parse error on line 1`.

Comment: @Auly What does `head -1 testcurl.json` show?  It's probably better to edit your question to show new information.

Comment: `head -1 testcurl.json` show null.